Behavior of polynomials in cyclotomic extensions of finite fields
I have a followup question to Factorization over cyclotomic extensions of finite fields
While I have got the answer for the situation where $x^4+1=(x^2+18x+1)(x^2+5x+1)$ in $(\mathbb{Z}/\langle 23\rangle)[x]$ and $x^4+1=(x-e^{\pi i/4})(x-e^{3\pi i/4})(x-e^{5\pi i/4})(x-e^{7\pi i/4})$ in $(\mathbb{Z}[e^{\pi i/4}]/\langle 23\rangle)[x]$, I still have some trouble understanding what becomes of $x^2+18x+1$ in $(\mathbb{Z}[e^{\pi i/4}]/\langle 23\rangle)[x]$.
Apparently there are only 4 primitive roots of unity and 6 possible combinations:

$(x-e^{\pi i/4})(x-e^{3\pi i/4})$
$(x-e^{\pi i/4})(x-e^{5\pi i/4})$
$(x-e^{\pi i/4})(x-e^{7\pi i/4})$
$(x-e^{3\pi i/4})(x-e^{5\pi i/4})$
$(x-e^{3\pi i/4})(x-e^{7\pi i/4})$
$(x-e^{5\pi i/4})(x-e^{7\pi i/4})$

which two of these choices would be a no go for $x^2+18x+1$ in $(\mathbb{Z}[e^{\pi i/4}]/\langle 23\rangle)[x]$?
